# Producer - Consumer Model; Storing Buffer Entry and Exit Times

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency

I am currently trying to solve a problem based around the producer - consumer model in relation to concurrent programming. I have a bounded buffer, storing integer values that enter and leave the buffer in a first in - first out manner.

What I want to do is randomize an amount of time that each object stays in the buffer, after which it will be flagged to the consumer that it is time to collect this object from the buffer.

My idea so far is as follows:

- at the producer end, an `int` is assigned for each value. As well as this `int` (used to identify the object) a date stamp would be created to store the time the object is put into the buffer
- whilst in the buffer, a random 'stay' time will be generated and added to this start time to create an exit time
- the consumer class will then search for firstly items in the buffer, and then for items that have reached their exit time, before removing that object from the buffer, using the `int` produced to identify which element has been removed

Is there any way to do this with one Array?

Should I be looking at parallel arrays, one for storing the integer that identifies each element, and a parallel index to store the entrance time?

In this last case I would then use 2 put methods in the buffer to assign the 'time stamp' to a parallel index in the second array.

Comment: You can use a blocking queue as a bounded buffer. Something like ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(int capacity) if you do not want to handle lower level thread synchrinization like using wait() and notify() methods in synchronized add/remove methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a **priority queue**. You just have to asign a random priority to each element when it is inserted. This priority will act as your *stay-time*. If your consumer will dequeue whenever there is an element in the queue then this should give you the same effect.

If you may have elements in the queue and you only dequeue them if the *stay-time* has passed, then you can use as priority (*current-time + random-stay-time*). In this case the consumer only have to check in a loop the head of the queue and verifies if the priority is equal to *current-time*.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a while but I thought it was worth giving feedback for anyone who finds this question in the future!

The solution lay in effective use of timestamps; as part of an object representing a customer coming to a department store (containing setters and getters for customer name, customer entrance etc.), a timestamp was saved when they arrived at the store, there was then a delay randomly assigned by the producer  (to represent a queue at the door) before they entered the buffer. Upon entering the buffer the time was recorded once again from the producer and saved to the customer object. Once in the buffer a second randomly assigned delay time was added to the initial enter time to represent shopping time. The consumer class searched every 5 seconds through the customer objects to see which customer (if any) were due to leave the store.

The above was achieved using only 1 array, as the times were stored in the customer object. I choose this method as it seemed to be much neater (in terms of using less code). A solution with 2 arrays would also work, just means a few more lines of code...

Hope that is clear enough to understand!

Thanks